# Load external environment parameters in Symfony 3.2 using env() at runtime return unresolved values

Tags: php, dependency-injection, configuration, symfony, ioc-container

I have a parameters file in an application using ***symfony 3.2 console, config and YAML component*** , and i try to set [external Parameters from environment](https://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration/external_parameters.html) variable in the Service Container parameters.

I create container builder.

```
$container = new ContainerBuilder();
```

Am using file locator to locate resources :

```
$container = new ContainerBuilder();
```

Loader resolver to load resources

```
LoaderResolver();
```

And using load method :

```
$this->load('parameters.yml');
```

**parameters.yml file:**

```
parameters:
  database:
    driver: pdo_mysql
    host: 127.0.0.1
    dbname: dbname
    user: env(VAL1)
    password: env(VAL2)
  Local: us-en
```

After compiling the container and try to check get values from parameters bag :

```
$container->getParameterBag()->all()
```

its return me values like this :

***env_VAL1_3ec776edc429c1734ed780a29a0af538* , *env_VAL2_3ec776edc429c1734ed780a29a0af538***

I think the container can't resolve those values from the environment .

Note : i set the environment variable using :

```
$ export VAL1='SOME TEXT'
```

Anyone has an idea why ?

Comment: Did you tried replace `"%env(VAL1)%"`  with `env(VAL1)`

Comment: Yes , and it doesn't work , it show me the value above.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So I've spent some time investigating this 'issue' and here is what I found out...

The only way to get `env(VAL1)` thingy working is to generate the container to PHP file using `PHPDumper` and then use the generated container. There is no other way to make it working because it only resolves environment in that file.

In the normal Symfony project there is a generated `var/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php` file. There is method `getDynamicParameter` which looks like this

```
 private function getDynamicParameter($name)
    {
        switch ($name) {
            case 'kernel.root_dir': $value = ($this->targetDirs[3].'/app'); break;
            case 'kernel.logs_dir': $value = ($this->targetDirs[2].'/logs'); break;
            case 'user': $value = $this->getEnv('VAL1'); break;
            case 'session.save_path': $value = ($this->targetDirs[3].'/app/../var/sessions/dev'); break;
            case 'router.resource': $value = ($this->targetDirs[3].'/app/config/routing_dev.yml'); break;
            default: throw new InvalidArgumentException(sprintf('The dynamic parameter "%s" must be defined.', $name));
        }
        $this->loadedDynamicParameters[$name] = true;

        return $this->dynamicParameters[$name] = $value;
    }
```

It is the only place where the `env(VAL1)` is evaluated.

So for your case the solution is the following.

I used simplified `parameters.yml`:

```
parameters:
    user: '%env(VAL1)%'
```

The `export` I did:

```
export VAL1=abc
```

PHP code:

```
$container = new ContainerBuilder();

$loader = new YamlFileLoader(
    $container,
    new FileLocator('.')
);

$loader->load('parameters.yml');

$container->compile();

$dumper = new PhpDumper($container);

$content = $dumper->dump(
    [
        'class' => 'DumpedContainer',
        'base_class' => 'Container',
        'file' => 'DumpedContainer.php',
        'debug' => true
    ]
);

// Use this code if you want to write file to the disk
$cache = new ConfigCache('DumpedContainer.php', true);
$cache->write($content, $container->getResources());
require_once $cache->getPath();

// ... otherwise use this code
//$content = str_replace('<?php', '', $content);
//eval($content);

$container = new DumpedContainer();

$user = $container->getParameter('user'); // $user = 'abc'
```

In the generated code you'll see the following method that do the magic

```
private function getDynamicParameter($name)
{
    switch ($name) {
        case 'user': $value = $this->getEnv('VAL1'); break;
        default: throw new InvalidArgumentException(sprintf('The dynamic parameter "%s" must be defined.', $name));
    }
    $this->loadedDynamicParameters[$name] = true;

    return $this->dynamicParameters[$name] = $value;
}
```

This solution works fine but looking at it I wonder if this is really needed in your project? What's wrong with `getenv()`?

Comment: Thank you for your answer , currently i don't do any caching in my application, and i want to use this without adding cache support in my application.
You shared a very useful information and i will try your code and try to provide you with my feedback.

Answer (score 1):

Please try:

```
parameters:
database:
    driver: pdo_mysql
    host: 127.0.0.1
    dbname: dbname
    user: '%env(VAL1)%'
    password: '%env(VAL2)%'
log_path: /logs
```

I think that's the problem. See this documentation for reference:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration/external_parameters.html

Comment: I do change the parameters , but nothing happen.

Comment: I think the problem related to kind of container extension , or compiling

Comment: Not certain. Did you clear your cache using: `php bin/console cache:clear --env=prod` ?

Comment: Am using Symfony console and config component , not in a Symfony project.

Comment: Does `getenv(VAL1)` work? Try with and without single quotes. Let me know and I'll update my post.

Answer (score -1):

If you use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase instead of \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase Symfony3 do the magic for you.

```
$client = static::createClient();
$this->container = $client->getContainer();
$user = $container->getParameter('user'); // $user = 'abc'
```

take a look on 
http://symfony.com/doc/current/testing.html#your-first-functional-test

With this method you will able to tweak also Symfony configurations using *_test.yml specific files.

I think this is the right way.