# parameters.yml env not working?

Tags: php, symfony, environment-variables

I am using a symphony components for a project I am working on. I would like to be able to set some parameters to environment variables. I have followed the docs here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration/external_parameters.html

But when I try to get the parameter from the container it does not return the correct value. See below:

env:

```
TEST_VAR = some_value
```

parameters.yml:

```
test: '%env(TEST_VAR)%'
```

php:

```
foreach ($extensions as $extension) {
    $container->registerExtension($extension);
}

$loader = new YamlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__ . 
'/Resources/Config'));
$loader->load('parameters.yml');

$loader = new XmlFileLoader($container, new 
FileLocator(__DIR__.'/Resources/Config'));
$loader->load('services.xml');

$container->compile();

var_dump(getenv('TEST_VAR'));
var_dump($container->getParameter('test'));
var_dump($container->resolveEnvPlaceholders($container->getParameter('test')));
```

Output:

```
string(20) "some_value"
string(45) "env_TEST_VAR_2f6516c3930c6d0eb09ff6373600c428"
string(15) "%env(TEST_VAR)%"
```

$container->getEnvCounters() returns:

```
array(1) {
  ["TEST_VAR"]=>
  int(0)
}
```

My issue seem to relate to this: [Load external environment parameters in Symfony 3.2 using env() at runtime return unresolved values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41338029/load-external-environment-parameters-in-symfony-3-2-using-env-at-runtime-retur)

Comment: `$container->compile(true)`, so the env vars are resolved

Comment: Does $container->compile take a parameter in ContainerBuilder?